# Remove NoneType from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I'm trying to remove the commas from the numbers I extracted with the following code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/paddington/?q=Paddington%2C%20London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home'
    r = s.get(url, headers=req_headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    prices = []
    for price in soup.find_all('a', {"class":"listing-results-price text-price"}):
        prices.append(price.text)
        if price is None:
            print('none')
    df['price'] = prices
    df['price'] = df['price'].str.extract('(\d+([\d,]?\d)*(\.\d+)?)', expand=True) #remove extract numbers with commas
    df['price'] = df['price'].replace(',','', inplace = True)
```

This returns a column in which all the values are None. Is there anyway to remove this NoneType error?

Before I run the final line the dataframe is as follows:

```
         price
0          NaN
1    1,875,000
2    4,950,000
3      500,000
4      675,000
5      980,000
6      475,000
7      849,950
8    1,050,000
9    1,050,000
10     650,000
11   1,100,000
12   1,300,000
13     895,000
14   1,000,000
15  26,800,000
16   1,600,000
17     695,000
18   2,100,000
19     510,000
20   1,200,000
21   3,000,000
22     599,000
23  26,800,000
24   1,550,000
25     750,000
26   1,600,000
27   1,025,000
```

Comment: Can you show us the input data?

Comment: I suggest you move your if condition one line earlier. :-)

Comment: @HarvIpan I have edited the post to show the data before trying to replace commas on the final line.

Comment: @cwallenpoole unfortunately values are still being returned as None

Comment: With `df['price'].replace(',','', inplace = True)` , you are replacing `inplace`, which does not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `df['price'].replace(',','', inplace = True)` , you are replacing `inplace`, which does not return anything.

You need:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',','')
```

Output:

```
0        NaN
1    1875000
2    4950000
3     500000
4     675000
5     980000
6     475000
7     849950
8    1050000
9    1050000
```

For reference, have a look at [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.html)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this just returns the exact same column as the input data (number with commas).

Comment: @James, umm, are you sure you are replacing your last line with the line `df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',','')`, notice the `.str` assessor. If you DO NOT use `.str` assesor, it would return the same data, as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should process it at data extraction end before constructing data frame you can construct your list as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/paddington/?q=Paddington%2C%20London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=home'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
res_lis = [int(price.text.strip().split('\n')[0].replace('£', '').replace(',', '')) for price in soup.find_all('a', {"class":"listing-results-price text-price"}) if price]
print(res_lis)
```

result:

```
[2000000, 549950, 1050000, 500000, 675000, 980000, 475000, 849950, 1050000, 1050000, 650000, 1100000, 1300000, 895000, 1000000, 26800000, 1600000, 695000, 2100000, 510000, 3000000, 1200000, 599000, 26800000, 1550000, 750000, 1600000, 1025000]
```

It's always better if you construct/manipulate all data according to requirement as much as possible before storing it which will be your data extraction phase and then